# Probability with inequalities

Tags: probability

Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are two independent variables with the same CDF $F(.)$ and $a$ is a constant. How do I write the below probability?

$x<-y<a$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can write it as follows 
as $$x<-y<a$$
$$-x>y>-a$$

$$P_r(-x>y>-a)=F(-x)-F(-a)$$

Comment: Thanks but x and y are both random variables. Don't we need to use their joint distribution? Are you sure that this is correct?

Comment: In particular, can we say P(y<-x)=F(-x) when x is a random variable?